# Angular 2, StyleUrls + Styles

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm unable to use both `styleUrls` + `styles` in Component (It appears whichever is declared last gets used).  What is the best way to get around this?

I want to use the `./board.component.css` to declare the base styles, but want to add the `terrainStyles` string which is generated using logic+data from DB.

I know I can write all my styles as strings, but I'd like to keep the majority of my styles within the css file.  Is there a good way to include logic in the css file?  Or something I haven't considered?

```
Component({
  selector: 'board',
  templateUrl: './board.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./board.component.css'],
  styles: [terrainStyles] // string generated using typescript logic
})
export class BoardComponent implements OnInit {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: CSS `@import` rule

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Webpack and had the same problem when trying to use both the `styles` and `styleUrls` properties.

I got around it by requiring the stylesheet I had defined in `styleUrls` in the `style` property instead.

```
styles: ['.something { display: block; }', require('./stylesheet.component.css')]
```